# how to run a UI created with QTdesigner in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am using pyqt5 designer to generate a simple gui and now i have no idea how to run that gui from python program

this is the python code that was generated using the pyqt5 designer :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'designeroDCGEn.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.15.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(506, 387)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName(u"gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(130, 100, 261, 131))
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalSlider = QSlider(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName(u"horizontalSlider")
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalSlider, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.progressBar = QProgressBar(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName(u"progressBar")
        self.progressBar.setValue(24)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 506, 21))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.progressBar.setValue)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

now i have no idea how to run this code in order to show the gui, running this code directly into the python IDE does nothing , i guess that is to be expected?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html):

```py
# Import UI from the generated python file
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # Use the auto-generated UI as the window's UI 
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        # Let QT update the current class using the auto-generated setupUI method
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
```